# Could not load file or assembly 'SMDiagnostics, Version=4.0.0.0

Tags: iis-8, windows-server-2012

I have a Windows 2008 server with IIS and a website there which its working fine.
I bought a new one server with Windows Server 2012 and i copied the files of the website to the new one.
When i'm opening the website to the new one i take the error
"Reference.svcmap: Could not load file or assembly 'SMDiagnostics, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest."
The site is for Net 4.
I searched for the error but none of the solutions was for my case.
Do you have any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the same missing DLL but for a Xamarin project in VS2015/2017

Comment: Yes I solve it by delete the web.config and put in place the default web.config. Then i added line by line from the old  web.config and tested.

Comment: I had many subwebsites to the main website and some lines of code to the web.config's of each made the error. I've cleared all and added line by line and tested. I don't know exactly which line raise the error but i think some websites they were for other version of framework